# creating dynamic dropdown based on json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a json data like this.

```
data = [{"value": "One", "value2": "1"},
{"value": "Two", "value2": "2"},
{"value": "Three", "value2": "3"},
{"value": "Four", "value2": "4"}]
```

I want to create dropdown with label of `value` and data-value of `value2`.

I'm able to create a dropdown by passing any one single column to a array like this.

```
chart_data = [];

data.forEach(function(d) {
   chart_data.push(d.value)
})

["one","two","three"] // result
```

With that result I create a dropdown using jquery's `$.each()` function.

```
$.each(chart_data, function(i, val) {
       $('#dropdown').append('' + val + '');
})
```

But over there I'm able to create using only single column.

I'm looking to create a dropdown from two column values with 1 col for the label and other for the data-value.

Comment: When you say 'dropdown' do you mean a `select` element, or another plugin?

Comment: Yes. That's `select`. I'll mention it right away.

Comment: @RGraham - I'm trying with the link you've given. But I have a challenge. When I'm about to append. My col has a space in the col name `value word`. How can I target it? I'm not able to enclose with this `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  var option = "<option value='"+d.value2+"'>"+d.value+"</option>";
  $('#dropdown').append(option);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to make a single array, I don't know why you are making that

Simply use your *data* field to populate your dropdown

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
   $('#dropdown').append(new Option(obj.value, obj.value2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the each on your data array.

```
$.each(data, function(i, o) {
  $('#dropdown').append('<option value="' + o.value + '">' + o.value2 + '</option>');
});
```